# SpreadSheetGear WorkbookView - Cells

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

I have a SpreadSheetGear WorkbookView in my form.
The SpreadSheetGear  WorkbookView has filled with excel file 10 rows and 10 columns.
I want to get the data from the cells using the code below:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < cells.Range.RowCount; i++)
 {
   for (int j = 0; j < cells.Range.ColumnCount; j++)
   {
     arrLstWorkBookView.Add(cells[i, j].Text);
     arrLstOutputData.Add(cells[i, j].Text);
   }
 }
```

and the debugger shows me `rowCount = 1048576` instead of `10`,
and `rowCount  = 16384` instead of `10`.

How to resolve the problem with WorkbookView and to take the right number of rows and columns from excel file   rows should be 10 and columns should be 10.

Comment: Unfortunately your values are coming from the full worksheet maximums rather than populated values: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Answer (score 5):

You don't provide a line of code that indicates where the `cells` variable is coming from, but if you are getting a row count of 1,048,576, this indicates to me that `cells` came from IWorksheet.[Cells](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~Cells.html)/[Range](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~Range.html), both of which represents all cells in a worksheet (A1:XFD1048576).

If you are trying to iterate over some smaller range within the worksheet, you'd need to specify this range with `IWorksheet.Cells["A1_Ref"]` or `IWorksheet.Cells[row1,col1,row2,col2]`. Example:

```
// The following two lines are equivalent
IRange cells = worksheet.Cells["A1:J10"];
IRange cells = worksheet.Cells[0, 0, 9, 9];
// ...the rest of your code...
```

If you want to iterate through the "used range" of a worksheet you would want to use IWorksheet.[UsedRange](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~UsedRange.html) instead.  Example:

```
IRange cells = worksheet.UsedRange;
```

Also, your call into Range in cells.Range.RowCount is redundant, as IRange.[Range](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Range.html) simply represents the specified IRange.  You could just use `cells.RowCount`.

You may also consider looking through our documentation for the IRange indexer (IRange.Item(…)), which demonstrates a number of different ways to reference cells:
    http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Item.html

Disclaimer: I work for SpreadsheetGear.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
SpreadsheetGear.IRange cells = worksheet.UsedRange;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know for sure the range is always 10x10, in which case it is just a matter of changing the loop conditions, you will need a way to detect consecutive values.

This code snippet should help you doing so

```
/// <summary>
/// gets the number of consecutive (without any empty cell) values vertically
/// </summary>
/// <param name="aRow"></param>
/// <param name="aColumn"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public int GetNumberConsecValues(int aRow, int aColumn)
{
   int wCount = 0;
   while (this[aRow + wCount, aColumn] != null)
   {
     wCount++;
   }
   return wCount;
}
```

and use it to read the values into an array/matrix as needed:

```
/// <summary>
/// Reads the vertical array from the specified cell
/// </summary>
/// <param name="aRow"></param>
/// <param name="aColumn"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public int[] ReadArrayInt(int aRow, int aColumn)
{
  int wNbValues = this.GetNumberConsecValues(aRow, aColumn);
  if (wNbValues == 0)
     return null;

  int[] wArr = new int[wNbValues];
  for (int iRow = 0; iRow < wNbValues; iRow++)
  {
    wArr[iRow] = Convert.ToInt32(this[aRow + iRow, aColumn]);
  }

  return wArr;
}
```

If you know the Range then you can use this other code snippet

```
public object[,] ReadRange(int aColFrom, int aColTo, int aRowFrom, int aRowTo)
{
  this.BeginUpdate();
  try
  {
    SpreadsheetGear.IRange oRange = m_ViewLock.Workbook.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[aRowFrom, aColFrom, aRowTo, aColTo];

    object[,] oValues = new object[aRowTo - aRowFrom + 1, aColTo - aColFrom + 1];

    int iRCol = 0;
    for (int iCol = aColFrom; iCol <= aColTo; iCol++)
    {
      int iRRow = 0;
      for (int iRow = aRowFrom; iRow <= aRowTo; iRow++)
      {
        oValues[iRRow, iRCol] = oRange.Cells[iRRow, iRCol].Value;
        iRRow++;
      }
      iRCol++;
    }
    return oValues;
  }
  finally
  {
    this.EndUpdate();
  }
}
```

Where BeginUpdate and EndUpdate are defined as:

```
/// <summary>
/// Must be called before the grid is being modified
/// We also call it inside every method so that if the user forgets to call it is no big deal
/// For this reason the calls can be nested.
/// So if the user forgets to make the call it is safe
/// and if the user does not forget he/she gets the full speed benefits..
/// </summary>
public void BeginUpdate()
{
  if (m_ViewLockCount == 0)
    m_ViewLock = new CWorkbookViewLockHelper(this.Workbook);

  m_ViewLockCount++;
}

/// <summary>
/// Must be called after the grid has being modified
/// </summary>
public void EndUpdate()
{
  m_ViewLockCount--;
  if (m_ViewLockCount <= 0)
  {
    m_ViewLock.Dispose();
    m_ViewLock = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way to get grids of data is through datatable as follows:

In the spreadsheet name a range

MyTable =Sheet1!$A$1:$J$11

This is MVC4 / Razor but it should translate to ASP.NET

```
<!-- language: c# -->
// Declare a DataTable variable
public DataTable myTable;

// Open the workbook.
String filename = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("myspreadsheet.xlsx");
SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook workbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook(filename);


//Get the table as a dataset:
DataSet dataSet = workbook.GetDataSet("MyTable", SpreadsheetGear.Data.GetDataFlags.FormattedText);
myTable = dataSet.Tables[0];

//Which can also be written as:
myTable = workbook.GetDataSet("MyTable", SpreadsheetGear.Data.GetDataFlags.FormattedText).Tables[0];
```

In my view I call a partial view with the name of the DataTable:

```
@Html.Partial("_DataTable", Model.myTable)
```

And the DataTable partial view looks like this:

```
@using System.Data;
@model DataTable
<table>
@{DataRow rowHead = Model.Rows[0];
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (DataColumn colHead in Model.Columns)       
            {
                <th>@rowHead[colHead.ColumnName]</th> 
             }
        </tr> 
    </thead>
}
    <tbody>
        @{int rowCount = 1;}
        @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
            {
                <tr>
                    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                    {
                        <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td> 
                     }
                </tr>
               rowCount = rowCount + 1;
            } 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

A quirk of this code is that the first row of the range is not available in the table. Somebody else needs to explain this but I believe that it is because the range is first fed  into a DataSet and the first row is preserved for column names. Perhaps some smarter code than mine can extract this in the partial view.

This example also shows how to render a DataTable from a spreadsheet range.

[SpreadsheetGear DataTable example](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/asp.net.sample.aspx?sample=amortization)